# MVC3 - Reference to inherited property fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a class PricingModel with two derived classes: Recurring and Packaged. in my home controller I make the following reference:

`ViewBag.X = db.PricingModels.Where(x => x.Type == "Packaged").Select(x => x).ToArray();
foreach (var o in ViewBag.X)
{
     var xy = o.Discount;
}`

which works fine.  If I change that to:

`var X = db.PricingModels.Where(x => x.Type == "Packaged").Select(x => x).ToArray();
foreach (var o in X)
{
     var xy = o.Discount;
}`

the reference to o.Discount complains:

> Error 2   'Website.Models.PricingModel' does not contain a definition for 'Discount' and no extension method 'Discount' accepting a first argument of type 'Website.Models.PricingModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\ekkis\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SkillScore\Website\Controllers\HomeController.cs   46  32  Website

I think that the ViewBag.X[0].Discount works because the ViewBag is untyped... the value's there but the compiler doesn't know about it.  My question is: why can't doesn't the compiler see the property of the derived class?

I tried casting it but to no avail:

```
...ToArray().Cast<Packaged>()
```

also:

```
var xy = ((Packaged) o).Discount;
```

so what am I missing?

Comment: ok.  I don't know wtf but this seems to work:
Packaged[] Packages = db.PricingModels.Where(x => x.Type == "Packaged").Cast<Packaged>().ToArray();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Cast() won't work for non native types. so I've ended up doing:

```
List<PricingModel> Packages = db.PricingModels
   .Where(x => x.Type == "Packaged")
   .ToList();
foreach (Packaged o in Packages) { ... }
```

which works just fine (finally!)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use the OfType extension method instead of Cast.

```
db.PricingModels.OfType<Packaged>.ToList()
```

Cast does exactly that - cast, however ofType will actually only return items of type Pacakged.
Also, the Select() is not needed as you're trasnforming an object of T to itself.

If I understand your code correctly, it might crash when a type is not a Packaged type.

And yes, the reason it works with the ViewBag is because the ViewBag is a Dynamic, so there is no compile-time checking as everything happens at runtime.